# CSS affects to all tables

Tags: html, css

I have 2 tables. One's ID is yourtable. Seconds mytable. When i write CSS for mytable it affects also yourtable. Why i cant figure out. 
Here is CSS code:

```
#mytable table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#mytable th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#mytable tr:hover{background-color:#f5f5f5}

#mytable tr th{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: post your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, '#mytable th, td' don't right selector

```
#mytable table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#mytable th, #mytable td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#mytable tr:hover{background-color:#f5f5f5}

#mytable tr th{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to post your HTML but I can see some problems with what you have given.

`#mytable table` would mean you have a table wrapped in a container element with the ID mytable, even without seeing your HTML code I'm going to guess you mean to select

```
table#mytable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Your second rule is targeting the table header under the `#mytable` table, but then you go on to target all table cells in all tables. Again, without seeing your HTML code I guess you probably mean to write:

```
#mytable th, #mytable td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Post your HTML code and I will update my answer specific to your situation